# Recreate height constraint

Tags: swift, snapkit

So I have a button that I want to toggle the height of a view with. This means I can't use priority to update these values. However, when I tap in the table it updates correctly.

```
let shown = false;
tableHeaderView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.width.equalTo(self.tableView.snp.width)
        make.height.equalTo(50)
    }
filterButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
    self.tableHeaderView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            if (shown) {
                make.height.equalTo(50)
            } else {
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
            self.shown.toggle()
    }
})
```

This code just breaks the constraint I want to add. How can I avoid this?

```
(
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x600002574780@AthleteSearchController.swift#54 UIView:0x7fccf0441c20.height == 100.0>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002235db0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fccf0441c20.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x600002574780@AthleteSearchController.swift#54 UIView:0x7fccf0441c20.height == 100.0>
```

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: remakeConstraints removes existing constraints tho

Comment: Can i just share the full code (150 lines)?

Comment: After that code block just add self.tableHeaderView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded